# Have files with querystring included in their name. Need nginx to ignore querystring for the content header

Tags: nginx, mime-type

Have a directory with lots of files. These are all static files from backups.

The issue is that some files that are named like the following:

```
mystyle.css?version=3.3.1
```

When serving the files, nginx is not detecting the file is a css, and thus doesn't send the `Content-Type: text/css` header and it is giving me some trouble. It is very troublesome to rename the files, since it would require renaming a ton of files, while also renaming them inside of html, javascript, etc. Could it be possible to assist nginx into ignoring the ? and the rest of the query string and only check mystyle.css for the determination of the kind of mimetype to serve?

This is particularly troublesome for things like SVG images, since the browsers don't detect them as such unless you serve them as `image/svg+xml`,
but this also causes trouble in other situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx looks at the final filename and concludes that the extension is `css?version=3.3.1`. It looks this up in the `types` block and finds no match, so the value of the `default_type` is used instead.

If you have all CSS type files under one folder and all SVG type files under another - or if the URI path for different types is unique, you can set the mime-type for all files within a particular location:

```
location /css {
    types { }
    default_type text/css;
}
```

---

From the first line of your question, you indicate that there is one directory with lots of files, presumably with different mime-types.

You can use a `map` directive with a regular expression to identify the mime-type of the files. You will need to add a line for every type of file contained in the directory. My example contains just a few. The file `/etc/nginx/mime.types` contains the types Nginx is usually configured to recognise, but you will only need to add the types of files you currently archive to this directory.

```
map $request_uri $type {
    default         application/octet-stream;
    ~*\.css         text/css;
    ~*\.js          application/javascript;
}

server {
    ...
    location /some/path {
        default_type "";
        types { }
        add_header Content-Type $type;
    }
}
```

DISCLAIMER: This is probably a hack, but appears to work.

Setting the `default_path` to an empty string together with an empty `types` block, prevents Nginx from adding its own Content-Type header.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details of the `map` directive.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on accepting the answer! Like anyone, I had a lot of stuff and moved on temporarily while attending more urgent matters. Just came back to this issue now. Thanks!